# Total differential of a function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let's consider a function 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{xy^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},& (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\ 0,& (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
does it have a total differential in point $(0,0)$?
I say that it does not, since I believe, that the limit does not exist. However, I was proven wrong by wolfram alpha, who says that it does exist and is $0$. I'd like to ask how to prove the limit exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another method:** Try $\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq x^2+y^2 \rightarrow 0$. Is this sufficient? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, because $0\leq xy\leq\frac{xy^3}{x^+y^}\leq x^2+y^2$ because of two policemen theorem and  we know that $\lim_{x,y\to0,0 }x^2+y^2=\lim_{xy}xy=0$

Answer (score 3):

Use polar coordinates: $x = r\cos(\theta)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)$. Then 
\begin{align}
f(r, \theta) = r^{3}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)^{3},
\end{align}
which show that the singularity at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ is removable. Differentiating with respect to $r$ or $\theta$ gives a function continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: You have a typo in the exponent of $\sin \theta.$

Comment: However, a function $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ also grants us, that the singularity disappears, but it does not have limit in (0,0).

Comment: Good catch. The coordinate transformation on @user74200's function would give $r\sin(2\theta)/2$, which when differentiated wrt $r$ would clearly show that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Using $$\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{1}{2}$$ we see that 
$$\left|\frac{xy^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |x|^{\frac{1}{2}}|y|^{\frac{5}{2}}$$ and so we see the limit at the origin is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Only @ChrisK is addressing your original question. They have argued that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Now you compute that both partial derivatives of $f$ at $0$ are $0$ and so the best linear approximation — if it exists — is the $0$ map. Now you must check that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(0x+0y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$$
But 
$$\left|\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^4}{x^2+y^2}=x^2+y^2\to 0,$$
as required.

Comment: Can you please explain how you reach the desired upperbound $\left|\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^4}{x^2+y^2}$ ? You referenced Chris' (inactive user) answer for this but I don't understand how we get that $xy^{3}\leq x^{4}+y^{4}$. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @John11: We have $|x|,|y|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.